# C#.NET: two tables by third relation table, but I can't group by one model via context (EF)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Desktop-App-Api | .NET-Core: 5.0 | EF-Core: 6.0.3 | HotChocolate: 12.7.0

I try to add a query method to an existing GraphQL api, to get the data from two tables *(three with the reference table)* via database *(MSSQL)*.

**StockPickingCarts**

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [db_owner].[StockPickingCarts] (
    [Id] [int] CONSTRAINT [PK__StockPickingCarts] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
)
```

**StockPickingCartLayouts**

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [db_owner].[StockPickingCartLayouts] (
    [Id] [int] CONSTRAINT [PK__StockPickingCartLayouts] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Rows] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Columns] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UQ__StockPickingCartLayouts__Rows_Columns] UNIQUE ([Rows], [Columns])
)
```

**StockPickingCartsCartLayouts** (relation table)

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [db_owner].[StockPickingCartsCartLayouts] (
    [Id] [int] CONSTRAINT [PK__StockPickingCarts_CartLayouts] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CartId] [int] CONSTRAINT [FK__StockPickingCartsCartLayouts_CartId__StockPickingCarts_Id] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [db_owner].[StockPickingCarts]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    [CartLayoutId] [int] CONSTRAINT [FK__StockPickingCartsCartLayouts_CartLayoutId__StockPickingCartLayouts_Id] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [db_owner].[StockPickingCartLayouts]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UQ__StockPickingCarts_CartLayouts__CartId_CartLayoutId] UNIQUE ([CartId], [CartLayoutId])
)
```

---

Here are the models...

**StockPickingCart**

```
using HotChocolate;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Common.Models.Warehousing
{
    public class StockPickingCart : IIdentifiable
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("IsActive")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public List<StockPickingCartLayout> Layouts { get; set; } = new List<StockPickingCartLayout>();
    }
}
```

**StockPickingCartLayout**

```
using HotChocolate;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Common.Models.Warehousing
{
    public class StockPickingCartLayout : IIdentifiable
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Rows")]
        public byte Rows { get; set; }

        [Column("Columns")]
        public byte Columns { get; set; }

        public List<StockPickingCart> Carts { get; set; } = new List<StockPickingCart>();
    }
}
```

**StockPickingCartsCartLayout**

```
using HotChocolate;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Common.Models.Warehousing
{
    public class StockPickingCartsCartLayout : IIdentifiable
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("CartId")]
        public int CartId { get; set; }

        [Column("CartLayoutId")]
        public int CartLayoutId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CartId")]
        public StockPickingCart Cart { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CartLayoutId")]
        public StockPickingCartLayout CartLayout { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PS: I never use that `StockPickingCartsCartLayout` model later in code, it's just the entity model for reference table. In my app I want to use `StockPickingCart` with containing Layouts and otherwise `StockPickingCartLayout` with containing Carts.

---

Then registerd all used database tables and look for keys...

**ToolDbContext**

```
using GraphQL.Domain.Models;
using GraphQL.Infra.Data.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace GraphQL.Infra.Data.Context
{
    public partial class ToolsDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ToolsDbContext(DbContextOptions<ToolsDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<StockPickingCart> StockPickingCarts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StockPickingCartLayout> StockPickingCartLayouts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StockPickingCartsCartLayout> StockPickingCartsCartLayouts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new StockPickingCartLayoutConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

**StockPickingCartsCartLayoutConfiguration**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace GraphQL.Infra.Data.Configuration
{
    internal class StockPickingCartsCartLayoutConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StockPickingCartsCartLayout>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<StockPickingCartsCartLayout> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("StockPickingCartsCartLayouts");
            builder.HasKey(ccl => new { ccl.CartId, ccl.CartLayoutId });
            /*
            builder.HasOne(ccl => ccl.Cart)
                .WithMany(c => c.Layouts)
                .HasForeignKey(ccl => ccl.CartId);
            builder.HasOne(ccl => ccl.CartLayout)
                .WithMany(l => l.Carts)
                .HasForeignKey(ccl => ccl.CartLayoutId);
            */
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out the lines I wasn't sure about (source: Google research). I think it will fill the List-Field of my model(s) by foreign key. But I think, that it creates a circle reference, because if each entry of Cart.Layouts contains a Layout which contains a Cart, which contains a... - Do yo see what I mean? Maybe I need a second model without list? Oh wait - that's the table `StockPickingCartsCartLayouts` (model: `List<StockPickingCartsCartLayout>`). - I feel lost, now. :/

So first of all... What's the best way to get a `List<StockPickingCart>` with a containing `List<StockPickingCartLayout>`? And otherwise to get a `List<StockPickingCartLayout>` with a containing `List<StockPickingCart>`? But both without circle reference? If possible not too much double code.

And second what's the best way for the method to get it?
I planned something like that *(untestet)*:

```
public List<StockPickingCart> GetStockPickingCarts(int? cartId = null)
{
  using var context = new ToolsDbContextFactory().CreateDbContext();
  var carts = ((cartId == null)
    ? context.StockPickingCarts
    : context.StockPickingCarts.Where(dbCart => dbCart.Id == cartId)
  ).ToList();

  return carts;
}
```

And this should return a Cart model containing a list of layouts. But it doesn't. :'( Maybe I need to use the reference table/model but I have no idea.

Without EF *(I was working with dapper the last 5 years)*, I would create a sql leftjoin with groupby the one side and finally mapped into the model and its containig list member. :/ But now I need to use EF and I'm so f***ing bad in EF. :(

So maybe somebody have an idea or maybe a better way *(I'm sure there is a flaw in my plan)*, then please let me know about.

Answer (score 0):

So...let me see if I get what you want...

Your StockPickingCartsCartLayouts has the foreign keys of StockPickingCarts and StockPickingCartLayout because its a many to may relation, right?
If so, then:

StockPickingCartsCartLayout

```
public class StockPickingCartsCartLayout : IIdentifiable
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("CartId")]
        public int CartId { get; set; }

        [Column("CartLayoutId")]
        public int CartLayoutId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CartId")]
        public virtual StockPickingCart Cart{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CartLayoutId")]
        public virtual StockPickingCartLayout CartLayout{ get; set; }

    }
```

StockPickingCart

```
public class StockPickingCart : IIdentifiable
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("IsActive")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<StockPickingCartsCartLayout> CartsCartLayout{ get; set; }
    }
```

StockPickingCartLayout

```
public class StockPickingCartLayout : IIdentifiable
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Rows")]
        public byte Rows { get; set; }

        [Column("Columns")]
        public byte Columns { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<StockPickingCartsCartLayout> CartsCartLayout{ get; set; }

    }
```